# How do I specify a literal number with a limited precision in an Oracle Database query?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I specify a literal number with a limited precision in the SELECT clause of an Oracle PL/SQL query?  Is CAST the only way?

I want to do this, but the column's type ends up as NUMBER, whereas I want the type to match `l.changed_rows_log_id`, which is a  `NUMBER(18,0)`.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(l.changed_rows_log_id, 1) AS Col1 FROM mytable l;
```

If I leave it at that, consuming processes may balk at type NUMBER since it might contain very large numbers--all because of a literal `1`.

Instead I have to do this, awkwardly.  Is there a better way?

```sql
SELECT CAST(COALESCE(l.changed_rows_log_id, 1) AS NUMBER(18,0)) AS Col1 FROM mytable l;
```

Comment: That will only feel awkward to you till you get used to it. Indeed, that's the common way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Isn't the problem more in the fact that your table stores numbers larger that the limit for  `int`  (`-2147483648 to 2147483647`) that in the `data type` of the expression?  `NUMBER(18,0)` can also store integers out of the limit.

Comment: Not quite, but I see the confusion out of my mistake in writing up the question.  I have edited my question, as it is indeed a 64-bit integer in Java (`long`).

Comment: .. and what was the value in `changed_rows_log_id` that lead to the overflow? I mean isn't *the confusion* on the client side making `getInt` instead of `getLong`? I still don't get the point how you can safe the client by casting the data type.

Comment: There is code outside my control that sees a NUMBER type and strictly cries "overflow" because it can happen in theory, even if not in practice.  Sorry, I didn't mean for this particular consequence to seem germane to the question.  I'll edit further.

Comment: Got it!  Check of metadata fails, so you'll have to `cast` down the datatype, which is exactly what you are doing;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no other way than using CAST as in the question.  Seems like a real shortcoming of PL/SQL syntax.